# center header in shiny dashboard boxes

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Im using shiny dashboard for an app, but cant find a way to center the title:

```
box(title = "Labels"
, status = "primary", solidHeader = T...
```

The "Labels title is in the left corner, of the box and would like it to be in the center, any ideas?

Comment: Try `title = h1("Labels", align = "center")`

Comment: So somehow the h1:h6 do get centered, but the size of the title box is massive, any idea on how to resize this?

Answer (score 0):

Some options for you...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"),

  dashboardSidebar(

    selectInput("dt","Data", choices = list("cars","mtcars","pressure")  )

  ),

  ## BODY

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 10, 

        box(title = h1("My Title with h1 ", align="center"),
            solidHeader = T,
            width = 5, height = 500,
            collapsible = T,
            plotOutput("plot1", height=350)
            ),
        box(title = h6("My Title with h6 ", align="center"),
            solidHeader = T,
            width = 5, height = 500,
            collapsible = T,
            plotOutput("plot2")
        ))), br(), br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8, align="center",
             box(title = div("My Title with div, red color and font-size 22 ", style='color:red; font-size:22px;'),
                 solidHeader = T,
                 width = 8, height = 500,
                 collapsible = T,
                 plotOutput("plot3")
             ) )
    )
      
  
  )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$dt)
    plot(get(input$dt))
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({plot(mtcars)})

  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({plot(pressure)})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some css to center text in the box.

> .box.box-solid.box-primary {
> text-align: center;
> }

```css
ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(title = "Centered Title Box Example"),
 dashboardSidebar(),
 dashboardBody(
  tags$head(
   tags$style(HTML("
   .box.box-solid.box-primary {
    text-align: center;
    }"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
   box(
    title ="Centered Title Box", 
    status = "primary",
    solidHeader = TRUE,
    collapsible = TRUE,
    width = 6,
    height = 200,
    plotOutput("plot")
   )
  )
 )
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMzX0.png)